# Getting a server to server access (google service account) token. invalid_grant error

Tags: node.js, google-api, jwt

I am getting

`{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}`

When I try to get an access token from Google. I am following https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount. I think perhaps the way I generate the JWT token is incorrect?

```
var header = { "alg": "RS256", "typ": "JWT" };
var body = {
    iss:'simplify-dev-calendar@simplify-dev-1188.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    aud: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    exp: Date.now() + ONE_HOUR,
    iat: Date.now(),
};
var token = jsrsasign.jws.JWS.sign('RS256', header, body, googleServicePrivateKey);
return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    superagent.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .send({
            grant_type: encodeURIComponent('urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'),
            assertion: token
        })
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(res.body);
        });
});
```

My googleServicePrivateKey looks like

```
'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCNPsOIG1HGgMhP\nG...
```

Isit ok? With those `\n`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem resolved using `kjwt` and omitting the expiry/issue date.